# List pattern Check

Tags: python, list

I want to solve one Issue related to List Pattern.
I have on one pattern list, **pattern=['A', 'B']** and one Actual list, **Actual =['A','B','A','B',A']**,I need to check that** Actual list** element following the pattern of **pattern** list or not

Condition1:

```
let say if Actual=['A','B','A','B','A']
and pattern=['A','B']
if this condition then i will receive in print **yes Actual list follow the pattern of pattern list**
But if Actual==['A','B','A','B','B']
then return **not matching with the pattern of pattern list and Capture the not matching postion and not matching Element of Actual list**.

Similarly for the other repetition of pattern like in condition 2.

Condition 2:
Actual=['X','Y','Z',X','Y']
pattern=['X','Y','Z']
if this condition then i will receive in print **yes Actual list follow the pattern of pattern list**.

but if Actual=['X','Y','Z','Y','Z']
pattern=['X','Y','Z']
if this the then return **not matching with the pattern of pattern list and Capture the not matching postion and not matching Element of Actual list**.

and many more like this.
```

i have tried using :

```
if Actual==pattern*int(len(Actual)/(len(Pattern))
    return True
else:
    #Capturing the misplace postion in the Actual list.
```

but Above one is only working when the both length of Actual list is a divisor of the pattern.

Can anyone suggest me any other Approach?

Note: length of Pattern list may vary.it not always 2 as like in the Above case.

Comment: What does "following the pattern of pattern list" mean? Do you mean that if the pattern is ABB then the actual must be one of ABB, ABBABB, ABBABBABB etc?

Comment: Here Pattern list is just a simple list, let say you assume X=['A', 'B'] and the pattern is basically the pattern of the elements of the list.

Comment: @jarmod I Already mention Conditions in the Question. please refer it.

Comment: @jarmod if Pattern is ABB and given list ABBAB that condition I want to check the order of occurrence of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in a rather cool way with `itertools`

```
from itertools import cycle, count

def f(actual,pattern):
    return all( a==b for a,b in zip(actual,cycle(pattern))) 

def mismatch(actual, pattern):
    return ( c for a,b,c in zip(actual,cycle(pattern),count()) if a != b)




#Some tests    
assert f(['A','B','A','B','A'],['A','B']) 
assert not f(['A','B','A','B','B'],['A','B']) 

assert list(mismatch(['A','C','A','B','B'],['A','B'])) == [1,4]
```

The function `cycle` will just keep repeating the pattern until it as long as the actual, then `all` will check element by element.

Comment: How to fetch mismatch position or index in the list.

Comment: @Rishav added mismatch functionality